# reference does not exist with custom function - google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to call [this](https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:tBTCUSD/hist?limit=1000&start=1577841154000&end=1606785154000&sort=-1) API response using a custom function where I can change the parameters. This is my code:

```
function callCandles(pair, start, end) {
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:" + "pair" + "/hist?limit=1000&start=" + "start" +"&end=" +"end" +"&sort=-1");
  
  var fact = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //parse the data from the API and store it in the variable data and convert response to text format//
  
  return fact;
  
}
```

This is what I'm typing in the spreadsheet:

```
=callCandles(tBTCUSD,"1577841154000","1606785154000")
```

But when I do it I get a "reference does not exist" error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify as follows and test it again.

#### Modified script:

```
function callCandles(pair, start, end) {
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:" + pair + "/hist?limit=1000&start=" + start + "&end=" + end + "&sort=-1");  // Modified
  
  var fact = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //parse the data from the API and store it in the variable data and convert response to text format//
  
  return fact;
  
}
```

- Please use `pair`, `start` and `end` as the variables.
- I thought that the reason of your error message is due to this. And also, please modify as follows.

#### Modified formula:

```
=callCandles("tBTCUSD","1577841154000","1606785154000")
```

- Please use `"tBTCUSD"` as a string enclosed by `"`.

#### Note:

- For example, when `pair` is used as `"pair"`, `pair` is the string value. By this, even when `=callCandles("tBTCUSD","1577841154000","1606785154000")` is used, `"tBTCUSD"` is not used and `"pair"` is used.
- When `=callCandles(tBTCUSD,"1577841154000","1606785154000")` is used, in this case, `tBTCUSD` is used as the named range. By this, when there is no named range of `tBTCUSD`, `#NAME?` is returned. By this, `pair` of `function callCandles(pair, start, end) {` is `#NAME?`. Please be careful this.

Comment: This worked!

I changed pair, start and end to variables and modified the formula to have tBTC in quotation makrs and removed the quotation marks from start and end in the formula. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific, in which line does the error occur?

Maybe the problem is that the variable you are passing the function are actually not used:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:" + "pair" + "/hist?limit=1000&start=" + "start" +"&end=" +"end" +"&sort=-1");
```

The parameter pair, start and end should be added without quotation marks. You should also use the newer syntax for some cleaner code:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1D:${pair}/hist?limit=1000&start=${start}&end=${end} &sort=-1`);
```

And as @tanaike pointed out, use `tBTCUSD` with quotation mark like this `"tBTCUSD"`

Comment: It works now. I changed pair, start and end to variables and modified the formula to have tBTC in quotation makrs and removed the quotation marks from start and end in the formula. Thanks a lot